# How can I process the values returned by a large number of coroutines on the fly (asyncio issue)?

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio, python-3.7, aiohttp

I have a very huge list of urls that I'd like to scrape. At first, I was thinking of doing something like this:

```
async def main(username, password):
    sem = asyncio.Semaphore(100)
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        await login(session, username, password)
        tasks = [asyncio.create_task(r_search(sem, session, url)) for url in hugenumberofurls]
        texts = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
```

But of course it's taking too long, and I'd like to process the results in real time (parsing + writing to a file). What would be the the most efficient way to achieve this goal?

Shall I chunk hugenumberofurls and then do:

```
async def main(username, password):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        await login(session, username, password)
        sem = asyncio.Semaphore(100)
        for chunk in chunk(hugenumberofurls):
            tasks = [asyncio.create_task(r_search(sem, session, url)) for url in chunk]
            texts = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
            process(texts)
```

I believe this could be a waste of time, as process() may take several seconds that could be used to keep on downloading urls...

I'd gladly take any piece of advice, asyncio and aiohttp are quite hard for a newcomer !

Answer (score 0):

Let's build a working example using two simulated operations:

```py
import random
import asyncio

async def fetch(url):
    """Simulate a network request"""
    await asyncio.sleep(random.random() / 10)
    return int(url.split("/")[-1])


def process(chunk):
    """Simulate a CPU-intensive task"""
    all(range(1, 10**8))
    return sum(chunk)
```

First, you need a way to [run the CPU-bound processing in an executor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor) in order to avoid blocking the rest of the program. For instance, a [ProcessPoolExecutor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor) could be use to parallelize the computation:

```py
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor

async def process_in_executor(chunk, executor=ProcessPoolExecutor()):
    """Run `process` in parallel using a process pool executor"""
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    return await loop.run_in_executor(executor, process, chunk)
```

Then you need a way to run the fetch requests concurrently while limiting the number of connections and gathering the results into chunks. This can be done using [asyncio.gather](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.gather) and/or [asyncio.Semaphore](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html#asyncio.Semaphore) but this can be really tricky to get right.

Instead, you could consider using the [aiostream](https://aiostream.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) library with the [stream.map](https://aiostream.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operators.html#aiostream.stream.map) and [stream.chunks](https://aiostream.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operators.html#aiostream.stream.chunks) operators that are designed for this purpose:

```py
from aiostream import stream, pipe

async def main():
    """Perform the following operations:
    1. Fetch a bunch of urls concurrently, with a limit of 100 tasks
    2. Gather the results into chunks of size 1000
    3. Process the chunks in parallel using 4 different processes
    4. Sum the results
    """
    urls = [f"http://my.url/{i}" for i in range(10000)]
    result = await (
        stream.iterate(urls)
        | pipe.map(fetch, ordered=False, task_limit=100)
        | pipe.chunks(1000)
        | pipe.map(process_in_executor, ordered=False, task_limit=4)
        | pipe.accumulate()
        | pipe.print("[progress - {}]")
    )
    print(f"> sum(range(10000)) = {result}")
```

This program should take a few seconds to run. Then you'll have to adapt the connection limit, the chunk size and the number of processes to your use case.

<sub>Disclaimer: I am the maintainer of the [aiostream](https://github.com/vxgmichel/aiostream) project.</sub>

Comment: Aiostream seems very convenient! If process(chunk) is parsing html for each url in chunk, shouldn'it be more straightforward to `async def parse(html)` and use `await parse(html)` from fetch(url)? And what if I want to write the results of process(chunk) to a file, say, a .csv?

Comment: @LoBellin It really depends on your use case and how cpu-intensive the parsing is. In my example a fetch operation takes about 50ms and the processing for one url is about 1.5 ms. With those constraints, using 4 processes to run the processing makes the program twice as fast. You'll have to experiment with those settings to figure out what's best for you, but I definitely suggest to start with the simplest configuration (i.e no chunking and no multiprocessing).

Comment: @LoBellin About the file writing you can either use the [csv module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) (preferably with an executor), or the [aiofiles](https://github.com/Tinche/aiofiles) library.

Comment: Alright I'm gonna give it a go. Do you know if I can pass several args to pipe.map(fetch, ordered=False, task_limit=100) ? I'd like to reuse a aiohttp.ClientSession(). Thanks a lot.

Comment: Does using starmap like this would work:         

`urls = [(session,url) for url in hugenumberofurls]
        result = await (
            stream.iterate(urls)
            | pipe.starmap(r_search, ordered=False, task_limit=100)
            | pipe.chunks(1000)
            | pipe.map(process_in_executor, ordered=False, task_limit=4)
            | pipe.accumulate()
            | pipe.print("[progress - {}]")
        )`

Comment: @LoBellin that would work, but it's probably simpler to use a [partial](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial): `pipe.map(partial(r_search, session), ordered=False, task_limit=100)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202424/discussion-between-lo-bellin-and-vincent).